# grant FILE privilege in Cpanel doesnt work

Tags: mysql

I tried:

```
USE mysql;
UPDATE user SET File_priv = 'Y' WHERE User = 'db_user';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

But I still receive the same error :

```
#1044 - Access denied for user 'gvcleb'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
```

Please it's my first time dealing with such problem. I need to know where exactly and how I can run such commands?

Comment: user **gvcleb'@'localhost** has no privileges to do that

Comment: how can I log in as root???